# Octal code for "Ctrl + left arrow" and "Ctrl + right arrow"

Tags: c++

I am working on a C++ game. I was trying to include character input using the `getch()` method. I need the character code (usually octal code) for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>◀</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>▶</kbd> to move my objects in the game.

Just like we have a code for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> that is `032`.

Here is part of the code I'm using.

```
if (kbhit())
    {
        gotoxy(x, y);
        cout << h;
        i = getch();
        if (i == '***') //I need some code here to move my object
        {
            x=x-5;
        }
        if (i == '***') //also need here to move it to right ward
        {
            x=x+5;
        }
        if (i == LEFT && x>LEFTLIMIT)
            {
                x = x - 3;
            }
        else if (i == RIGHT && x<RIGHTLIMIT-6)
        {
            x = x + 3;
        }
    }
```

Comment: They have no octal code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using modifier keys I'd suggest using `GetAsyncKeyState` : [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx)

This way you can check for every key pressed currently or since last call of `GetAsyncKeyState`

```
if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT) && GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CONTROL)) {
    ....
}
```